# Отсортировать набор картинок так, чтобы они "оптимально" вписывались в контейнер заданной ширины

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Есть набор картинок одинаковой высоты и разной ширины, и есть контейнер некоторый ширины, в который эти картинки надо укомпоновать с минимальной суммарной ошибкой следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Серым обозначены картинки, красным - ошибка. Принцип: картинки последовательно заполняют строку с некоторым отступом, а если следующая картинка выходит за ширину контейнера, то она идет с новой строки, неиспользованная ширина предыдущей (либо последней) строки - ошибка. Надо найти такой порядок следования картинок, чтобы суммарная ошибка была минимальной.

Comment: Ха, сейчас мозг потренирую , даже интересно .

Comment: @DigitalCore, задача возникла как прикладная (укомпоновать логотипы производителей в интернет-магазине), но похожа на олимпиадную, а может вообще только полный перебор.

Comment: логотипы должны идти по очереди, или в случайном порядке ?

Comment: @DigitalCore, в том порядке (наверное, их, последовательностей, может быть много), при котором ошибка минимальна. Их отсортировать надо, в принципе.

Comment: задача минимизации пустого места равносильна минимизации количества строк... для поиска глобального оптимума, пожалуй только полный перебор пойдёт.... Для практических целей скорей всего жадный алгоритм даст вполне достойный результат. Да, какова всё же типичная сложность задачи? И ориентировочные требования по времени?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Answer (score 1):

**На Оскар не претендую, код на C# (метка любой-язык).**

> 1. генерируем 200 картинок фиксированной высоты, и произвольной длинны.
> 2. добавляем в `List<images>`
> 3. сортируются по длине изображения
> 4. определяем помещается ли изображение самого большого размера в строку
> 5. определяем помещается ли изображение самого малого размера в строку

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sort_Picture_In_block
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        private List<Images> l = new List<Images>();
        private int m = 1000; // максимальная длинна строки в пикселях
        private int p = 10;   // расстояние между изображениями

        class Images
        {
            public Images(int width, Image image)
            {
                this.width = width;
                this.image = image;
            }

            public int width { get; set; }
            public Image image { get; set; }
        }

        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SortImages();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rend = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                int w = rend.Next(50, 250);
                Image bmp = new Bitmap(w, 50);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                Color color = Color.Black;
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, w - 1, bmp.Height - 1);
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), rectangle);
                l.Add(new Images(w, bmp));
            }
            l = l.OrderBy(images => images.width).ToList();
        }


        private void SortImages()
        {
            while(l.Count > 0)
            {
                int s = 0;
                int i = 0;
                while (s + p < m && l.Count() > 0)
                {
                    if (m - (s += p) > l[l.Count() - 1].width)
                    {
                        Image img = l[l.Count() - 1].image;
                        l.Remove(l[l.Count() - 1]);
                        s += img.Width;
                        // пишем картинку в строку ...
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (l.Count() > 0 && m - s > l[0].width)
                    {
                        Image img = l[0].image;
                        l.Remove(l[0]);
                        s += img.Width;
                        // пишем картинку в строку  ...
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtLog.Text += $"Длинна строки = {s} px, картинок {i} шт. \r\n";
                        s = m;
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]